# Searching in HashMap instead of database

Tags: java, hashmap

I have to look up prices depending on 1 value in my database. The database table contains 40000 entries with id, name, minvalue, maxvalue, price. I look up the correct price for value 2 with e.g.

```
SELECT name, price FROM priceTable WHERE minvalue <= 2 AND maxvalue >= 2;
```

Because i have to look up many prices (10000 and more) i thought about using something like a HashMap, with all the table data inside, so I would only have 1 database request and the rest would be done locally.

Has anyone experience with this? Is it possible to "convert" the SQL-request into a efficient HashMap-lookup? I cannot use the value as keys to look up, because e.g. the matching entry for the example above has minvalue 1 and maxvalue 3. So there would not be a key "2".

Comment: The terms you are looking for are ORM and level 2 cache (in case of hibernate).

Comment: You can configure your database such that certain keys are hashed.

Comment: actually, you can do it, but correct database querys are more efficient than store into java objects

Answer (score 1):

Java offers the `NavigableMap` interface that provides some interesting navigation methods including:

`subMap(fromKey::inclusive, toKey::exclusive)`

`headMap(toKey, boolean inclusiveOrNot)`

`tailMap(fromKey, boolean inclusiveOrNot)`

It will work for one type of key though (for convenience let's say it is somehow equivalent to an sql index; you need two indices here). Thus, in your case, you will need to store the `priceTable` using two different maps, one for minValue and one for maxValue eg:

```
NavigableMap<Double, List<Product>> minValueMap = new TreeMap<Double, List<Product>>();
NavigableMap<Double, List<Product>> maxValueMap = new TreeMap<Double, List<Product>>();
```

Then, to get `minvalue <= 2 AND maxvalue >= 2` you have to run:

```
Map<Double, List<Product>> minConditionMap = minValueMap.headMap(2, true);
Map<Double, List<Product>> maxConditionMap = maxValueMap.tailMap(2, true);
```

Your result is the intersection of these maps (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180488/intersection-of-java-util-map))