# intersection of map values and set

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a hypothetical map - `HashMap<String,List<String>> mapteachertostudents`.
There is a separate set - `Set<String> giftedstudents`.
The ask is simply print out the common students  using java 1.7

```
mapteachertostudents { 'A':'a,b,c';'B':'b,e';'C':'b,c,f'}
giftedstudents ['b','c','e']
expected output ['b']
```

Is there a more efficient routine than iterating each teacher and maintaining state,considering that this comparison has to be run over 10000+ maps each.

Comment: Please show the code to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: So the "common students" are those who are in giftedstudents and in each list of the map? Something else? What?

Comment: With `mapteachertostudents.keySet()` you can retrieve the set of keys from the map. Then it see the captioned answer

Comment: Checkout this answer as well for map intersection : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13180552/48136

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every possible algorithm is going to involve iterating over all the teachers and checking each teacher's students, there is no way around that. As far as efficiency goes, I think `retainAll` should be the most efficient way to derive set intersections in Java.

```
public static <T> Set<T> intersect(
        Collection<? extends Collection<T>> sets) {
    if (sets.isEmpty()) return Collections.emptySet();

    Iterator<? extends Collection<T>> it = sets.iterator();
    Set<T> intersect = new HashSet<>(it.next());
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        intersect.retainAll(it.next());
    }
    return intersect;
}
```

This allows you to then do

```
Set<String> commonStudents = intersect(mapteachertostudents.values());
```

The generics make the method general-purpose, so it isn't restricted to just `HashMap<String,List<String>>`, you can use it to intersect any collection of collections.