# How to make a collection for the Meet-In-The-Middle attack?

Tags: java, encryption, collections, hashmap

I want to create a collection, which can be used to find matches among the values. As you properly know, recovering the key for Double DES takes three steps. Having the plaintext and the ciphertext given:

1. Encrypting the plaintext with all 2^56 possible keys and storing the results
2. Decrypting the ciphertext with all 2^56 possible keys and storing the results
3. Checking where the results match to retrieve the key

What I am trying to do:
I am currently working with Meet-in-the-middle attack on Double DES and I have reached the point where I have to encrypt/decrypt a plaintext/ciphertext 2^56 times and store the results in order to find any matches.

Right now, I have stored the results in two `HashMaps` where I store the key used and the result from the encryption/decryption. However, I am not able to figure out how I can compare the results from the two `HashMaps` and then decide which keys have been used.

So, my second idea is maybe to use `ListMultimap` instead where I can store the results from the encryption/decryption with the key used, but then again, I don't know how to find the matches. The matches are not necessarily on the same row.

EDIT:

I gave it a try with my two HashMaps, but I did not succeed i.e. I was not able to compare the Maps

```
for (int i = 0; i <  Math.pow(2, 20); i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < Math.pow(2, 20); j++) {

        if(hmap1.values().toArray()[i].equals(hmap2.values().toArray()[j]) )    
             System.out.println(hmap1.keySet().toArray()[i] + " = " + hmap2.keySet().toArray()[i] );    
        }
 }
```

I forgot to mention that for the sake of testing, I am working with keys that have 20 effective bits. So, there will be 2^20 possible keys

I also forgot to mention what my HashMaps contain of. They contain of two byte arrays `static Map<byte[], byte[]> hmap1 = new HashMap<byte[], byte[]>();` where the first byte array contains of the possible key and the second array contains of the result of the encryption/decryption

Comment: You need one loop not double. One loop iterates one hashmap inside search in the second.

Comment: You do not store the results of #2.

Comment: Use set intersection as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180488/intersection-of-java-util-map)

Comment: @JamesKPolk: Then how am I going to find the the key for the decryption?

Comment: Unfortunately you have left off critical details on your implementation. You say you have HashMaps but you don't say what is the HashMap lookup key and its value. Since you have DES keys and DES encryption results it matters.

Comment: My HashMaps contain of two byte arrays where the first byte array contains of the possible key and the second array contains of the result of the encryption/decryption

Comment: Well, that's the wrong order of keys and output. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic outline:

You obtain a plaintext and ciphertext pair (P, C) which you know is the result of Double DES:

C = DES<sub>k2</sub>(DES<sub>k1</sub>(P))

Now going forward you create, say, a HashMap that maps DES intermediate output to the DES key k1 that created it. So this is important: don't get confused by the HashMap *keys* and the DES *keys*, this is just an unfortunate name overload. To avoid confusion I'll call the DES keys *cryptokeys*. So the HashMap is **from** 64-bit DES outputs **to** 56-bit (or 20 bit in the case of your toy) DES cryptokeys.

Java psuedo-code:

```
Map<Long, CryptoKey> forwardMap = new HashMap();
for (CryptoKey k1=0; k1 < (1 << 20); k1++) {
    Long intermediateCipher = DES-Encrypt(k1, P);
    forwardMap.put(intermediateCipher, k1);
}
```

Now to run the attack in Java psuedo-code:

```
for(CryptoKey k2=0; k2 < (1 << 20); k2++) {
    Long intermediateCipher = DES-Decrypt(k2, C);
    if (forwardMap.contains(intermediateCipher)) {
        k1 = forwardMap.get(intermediateCipher);
        System.out.printf("k1=%s, k2=%s work", k1.toString(), k2.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `byte[]` as the key, it doesn't implement `hashCode` and `equals`, so it won't work, i.e. `forwardMap.contains(intermediateCipher)` will always return `false`

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner: Thanks, I will change it.

Comment: @JamesKPolk; I just want to be sure about something. What is CryptoKeys in the for loop? I read that you have named the DES keys cryptokey, but how do I use them in a for loop?